# SendOrderedBroadcast

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver

Просьба подробно объяснить, как работает данный метод 
sendOrderedBroadcast, и показать на полном рабочем примере...

Comment: @Andreyua, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: http://www.truiton.com/2013/04/android-sendorderedbroadcast-example-with-priority/